# Select Options - Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, slider

I have this codes:

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    var s1 = $('#clarityfrom');

    var slider = $('#slider').slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 6,
        values: [s1[0].selectedIndex + 1],
        slide: function (e, ui) {
            var r1 = $('#clarityfrom option').eq(ui.values[0]-1).text();
            s1.val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#clarRange').html('<a href="?bplan='value of option'" class="btn btn-success">Buy '+r1+'</a>');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="clarRange">Select a Plan</div><br />
<select name="clarityfrom" id="clarityfrom">
    <option value="1">10.000 Coins + 5.000 Pixels - 150 Rubys</option>
    <option value="2">20.000 Coins + 10.000 Pixels - 300 Rubys</option>
    <option value="3">40.000 Coins + 20.000 Pixels - 600 Rubys</option>
    <option value="4">60.000 Coins + 30.000 Pixels - 900 Rubys</option>
    <option value="5">90.000 Coins + 40.000 Pixels - 1200 Rubys</option>
    <option value="6">120.000 Coins + 50.000 Pixels - 1500 Rubys</option>
</select>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

When the user select the option by slider, the script just change the text of "a" tag.
I need to change the text and the **href=""** according to the selected value.

Ex:

`<a href="?bplan=1" class="btn btn-success">Buy 10.000 Coins + 5.000 Pixels - 150 Rubys</a>`

Is a little confused, but I hope you understand

Comment: Change the href of what?

Comment: You have no r2 defined. You need $('#clarityfrom option:selected').text()

Comment: var r2 = $('#clarityfrom option:selected').text(); - doesn't worked

Comment: You should setup a fiddle.